# Snowflake Timestamp conversion

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following code gives me the value of Fri Aug 06 2021 12:16:27 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) instead of mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss. What am I missing here? Please advise

```js
create or replace procedure Load_Employee()
  returns varchar not null
  language javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  

  as
  $$
  //Variable Initialization
    
    var IntegrationTable ='EMPLOYEE';
    var TypeID=0;
    var MaxDate=' ';
    var cmd = "Select max(COMPLETED_DATE) from SCHEMA.TABLE where TARGET_TABLE_NAME=  " + "'" + IntegrationTable + "'"  ;
  
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    result.next();
 
   MaxDate=result.getColumnValue(1);
   return MaxDate;


  
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: That's how JavaScript will render a date variable if used as string. You can

Answer (score 0):

That's how JavaScript will render a date when presented as a string. You can change to YYYY-MM-DD like this:

```
create or replace procedure Load_Employee()
  returns varchar not null
  language javascript
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
  

  as
  $$
  //Variable Initialization
    
    var IntegrationTable ='EMPLOYEE';
    var TypeID=0;
    var MaxDate=' ';
    var cmd = "Select max(COMPLETED_DATE) from SCHEMA.TABLE where TARGET_TABLE_NAME=  " + "'" + IntegrationTable + "'"  ;
  
    var sql = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
    var result = sql.execute();
    result.next();
 
   MaxDate=formatDate(result.getColumnValue(1));
   return MaxDate;



// Helper functions

function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        hour = '' + d.getHours(),
        minute = '' + d.getMinutes(),
        second = '' + d.getSeconds(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;
    if (hour.length < 2) hour = "0" + hour;
    if (minute.length < 2) minute = "0" + minute;
    if (second.length < 2) second = "0" + second;

    return [month, day, year].join('/') + " " + [hour,minute,second].join(':');
}
    
  
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but how do I pass value from this function to Maxdate making Maxdate as mm/dd/yyyh hh:mm:ss?

Comment: You can just change the order of the join line and on the same line change the separator character from "-" to "/". I changed it in the answer.

Comment: Sorry I meant how to pass the output from the function to my variable Maxdate?

Comment: It's already done on this line `MaxDate=formatDate(result.getColumnValue(1));`

Comment: I see . Thank You very much

Comment: When the date is NULL the value returned is ' 12/31/1969 16:00:00'. Do you know why this may be happening?

Comment: Unix epoch time, which JavaScript implements in part, starts with 1/1/1970 at midnight. This looks like it's returning the start of the epoch adjusted for time zone. You can change the UDF definition to RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT.

Comment: Should this line be specified in the UDF? If so where as I could not find out

Comment: You have the definition of the stored procedure's return as "varchar not null". Do you want to change that to return null if MaxDate is null?